# Create with associated instances - Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sql, database-design, sequelize.js

Using sequelize ORM you can create with association in one swoop:

```
Product.create({
id: 1,
  title: 'Chair',
  Tags: [
    { name: 'Alpha'},
    { name: 'Beta'}
  ]
}, {
  include: [ Tag ]
})
```

My question is: How would I go about this when I have to work with an array of an **arbitrary** number of elements (here Tags) passed along?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. What problems are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear. But if you mean what if you have many attributs like Tags which are associations, maybe what you are looking for is:

```
include: [{
    all: true
}]
```

or

```
include: [{
    all: true,
    include: [{
        all: true
    }]
}]
```

For nested elements.